# Google AJAX Feed API vs ATOM/RSS

Tags: rss, atom-feed, google-feed-api

What is the difference between Google AJAX Feed API and the classics ATOM/RSS? Are they concurrents?

Answer (score 0):

The google API is a means to consume any standard rss or atom feed. Javascript is used to download any any public rss, atom or media rss feed. The feed can then be used with other content as with mashups.